# Mongoose + NodeJS - Error trying to return number of documents in a collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    image: {type: String, required: true},
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    description: {type: String, required: true},
    price: {type: Number, required: true, min: 0},
    category: {type: String, required: true}
});

const Product = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);

router.get("/", async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const products = await Product.find().countDocuments();
        res.status(200).send(products)
    }
    catch(err) {
        res.status(500).send("unexpected error occurred");
    }
});
```

I am expecting the server to send the number of documents in the product collection but instead it goes to the catch block. I have been reading the mongoose docs, it seems like I am doing it correctly, however, something is going wrong.

Comment: what is the error, can show full error.

Comment: Please, add a `console.log` to the catch block in order to see what error is it throwing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the error 'invalid status code'. You just have to use backticks to avoid the error :

```
router.get("/", async(req, res) => {
  try {
      const products = await Products.find().countDocuments();
      res.status(200).send(`${products}`)
  }
  catch(err) {
      res.status(500).send("unexpected error occurred");
  }
});
```